# Where to find a DivA or DivX scanner in Spain?

Tags: tax-refunds

I purchased an iPad in Logroño and got a form for IVA reimbursement.  It says I should scan it at a DivX or DivA kiosk!  (Can't tell if the weird "letter" is an X or an A.)  Where do we find such a thing?

The alternative is a customs official stamping it—can we get that at the port of Barcelona before getting on a cruise ship?  Or in Gijón, the ship's last Spanish port?

Answer (score 1):

According to this page (in Spanish) https://www.globalblue.com/business/spain/diva3/ the only DIVA scanner currently in existence is based beside customs at Terminal 1 in Madrid airport. The page is dated 2018 so presumably that is still true. Assuming you have time at Barcelona it would seem wise to try there first. It may be though that the rules mean that your stop at Gijon would mean that technically you are not eligible to claim in Barcelona, you would have to ask them.

Comment: "hope they do not realise you are technically not leaving Spain yet" -- I'm not convinced that attempting to deceive customs, even by omission, is a good idea

Comment: @waiwai933 on reflection you are right. I will edit the post.

Comment: I asked for the form that allows me to get the refund by check, since it irks me to let the people at the airport keep half the IVA for themselves.  But this form says the store kept a third of it!  I made the mistake of thinking it was like Netherlands, where you send the form to a government office and get ALL of the tax back.  (In a check for Euro which is a challenge to cash in USA)

Comment: After Gijón, we go to Southampton.  Since they haven't left EU yet, it may be possible to get the stamp there.  But if not, it's too late!